# How to do Many to Many relations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

What is the correct way to do many to many in Rails?

I wasted a bit of time on the subtleties of this, so I thought I would post the question and the answer here, in the case that it saves someone else some time.

Comment: check this doc http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question here, as it was not immediately apparent. So I wanted to make sure if others were in the same pickle that this hopefully helps them.

So firstly with Rails for those new to Rails.. when you generate a Model eg "Story", the generator will pluralise the Model when creating the table name for the database eg "stories". So eg when I ran "rails g model author_book", the model ends up called AuthorBook and rails names the table author_books.

Keep that in mind when choosing Model names, as initially "Story" was named "News", which violated the rails convention of having Models named in the singular form.

Also another note: Don't have really long model and primary key names, as when rails hooks up the many to many relation in the database it can cause issues as it is limited to a max of 64 chars (from what I can remember).

So for the example let say we have Books and Authors and a relation between them. Here is how they will be represented in rails:

**app/models/book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_many :author_books        #This is the database table name!!
  has_many :authors, through:   #This is the database table name!!
end
```

**app/models/author.rb**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :author_books                    #This is the database table name!!
  has_many :books, through: :author_books   #This is the database table name!!
end
```

**app/models/author_book.rb**

```
class AuthorBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author_id, :book_id
  belongs_to :author                            #This is the MODEL name
  belongs_to :book                              #This is the MODEL name
end
```

**20131025011112_create_author_books.rb** migration example:

```
class CreateAuthorBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :author_books, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :author  #this is the MODEL name
      t.belongs_to :book   #this is the MODEL name
    end
    add_index :author_books, [:author_id, :book_id], :unique => true   #This is the database table name!!
  end
end
```

I hope that saves someone else some time!

Comment: No need to declare `AuthorBook` as a seperate model. Just make sure the database table is named correctly like you already did and declare the relationship like described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association so it would be `has_and_belongs_to_many :books` for `Author`

Comment: This QA is completely unnecessary, the topic is covered in great length with minimal searching.